# How to force hiDPI scaling mode on boot in Pop!_OS/Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, login, display-settings, high-dpi

I asked a similar question about hiDPI scaling [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530753/hidpi-scaling-fix-for-davinci-resolve-16-in-gnome). This question regards  a universal hiDPI mode, the other question is about fixing scaling on a specific application.

I am using a 4k monitor in Pop!_OS 19.04 running Gnome.

The OS automatically detects this and changes into hiDPI mode, but only after I log in after boot.

This means the log in screen when I boot is far too small. Additionally, when I log in, the screen flickers and I get a notification `Displays Set to HiDPI mode` every time. The problem does not arise when suspending the computer.

The command to change to hidpi mode manually is

`gsettings set com.system76.hidpi enable true`

but this does not seem to permanently change to hidpi mode. Running this command in `Startup Applications` does not work either.

Is there a way to permanently change to hiDPI mode so the OS doesn't have to change it every time I boot? Or change the default setting to hiDPI somehow?

Comment: Are you using `gdm` or `lightdm`?

Comment: @Paradox I am using `gdm`

Comment: Are you using `Wayland` or `x11` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your are using `gdm`, this should work for you system-wide:

### 1) Open the configuration file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml
```

### 2) Change the default value to the scaling factor you want (e.g. 2):

```
<key name="scaling-factor" type="u">
<default>2</default>
```

### 3) Apply the changes:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

It works with `gdm` using `x11`, not sure about `Wayland`.

Comment: This works great, and the login screen looks good, but after I log in the system still notifies me "Displays Set to HiDPI mode at startup" and the screen flickers. It doesn't do anything, but is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Nevermind, you can suppress the notification and screen flickering by disabling the HiDPI daemon in settings. I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: @HansJ Can you share how you disabled the HiDPI daemon? I get this notification every time I reboot too. Thanks!

Comment: @Paradox **Thank you so much!** This technique still works in the latest PopOS 20.10! I was having so much trouble running PopOS in a VMware virtual machine on a 4K display. I NEED 200% scaling, but every time the VM rescaled itself due to going in/out of fullscreen mode, the PopOS scale reset itself to 100%. You rescued me. Your fix makes PopOS set itself to 200% all the time (via "2" for this scaling setting), instead of trying to "auto-guess based on monitor = 100%" (the default "0" value for this scaling setting). Fix works PERFECTLY. Do NOT tweak the "text-scaling-factor 1.0" setting btw!

Answer (score -1):

You could add to set per boot some other way (I'm not entirely sure how 'Startup Applications' works). There are a couple ways to do this:

1. You could do it with cron. To edit your crontab run `crontab -e` and it will open up the crontab file with your preferred editor (or it might prompt you to choose an editor). Then adding an entry at the bottom would allow you to run a command at boot. For example, to run an echo command that runs every time I reboot my machine I'd add `@reboot echo "Hello" > ~/hello.txt` (Please note that if you wish this to be ran as root you'll have to run `crontab -e` as root).
2. You could add it to a /etc/rc.local file. This might not exist on your system, but it'd normally be the last thing to run before your login manager. To add something you could run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and paste in something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set com.system76.hidpi enable true
exit 0
```

Hope this helps, I sadly don't have a way to test either of these methods and don't know a way of setting to hiDPI permanently (without setting it per boot).

Source(s): https://www.simplified.guide/linux/automatically-run-program-on-startup

Comment: I do not think that will help since it happens even before log in into GNOME.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither of these solutions seem to work. This could be an issue with the login manager being set to lowdpi mode at startup.

Comment: It might also be because `gsettings` only works for GNOME itself, the login manager would be separate. I also wouldn't be surprised if it's set to lowdpi for compatibility, as this is something that'll run pre-Xorg.