# hiDPI scaling fix for Davinci Resolve 16 in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, high-dpi

I asked a similar question about hiDPI scaling [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530748/how-to-force-hidpi-scaling-mode-on-boot-in-pop-os-gnome). This question regards fixing scaling on a specific application, the other question is about a universal hiDPI mode.

I am running ubuntu derivative Pop!_OS 19.04 in Gnome. Edit: I have found this issue arises in CentOS, Fedora, and Debian as well.

I built a .deb package for DaVinci Resolve 16 with [MakeResolveDeb](http://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb) and it seems to work fine, but it does not scale properly.

Scaling looks similar to [this](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/download/file.php?id=8882&sid=ac3ab6b338e3fb25d7d58c4410b6677e)

This is a known (unfixed) issue, as seen [here](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?t=50161)

The solution [runscaled](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled) doesn't seem to work.

Is there a known way to solve the scaling issue for this specific application?

Comment: I'll also point out a really similar question of your asked very recently: [How to force hiDPI scaling mode on boot in Pop!_OS/Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/530748/117549). I would suggest that you mention it directly so that you can distinguish these two questions -- so that any well-meaning close-voters don't mix them up.

Comment: Is the issue that your app scales properly in CentOS but not in Ubuntu/Debian? Or does your app also not scale properly in CentOS too?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix
This is an issue consistent with both Ubuntu/Debian and CentOS

Answer (score 2):

For easy launching in HiDPI make these changes to the desktop shortcut, for example with nano editor:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/com.blackmagicdesign.resolve.desktop
```

change the Exec line value:

```
Exec=bash -c "QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=2 QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=true /opt/resolve/bin/resolve"
```